# How can I turn a monadic function into a monadic state transformer?

Tags: haskell, io, monads, state

Basically, what I want is this:

```
stateIO :: (s -> IO (a, s)) -> StateT s IO a
stateIO f = do
    r <- get
    (a, r') <- liftIO $ f r
    put r'
    return a
```

I tried to use `state`, but the inner `liftIO` is problematic. Is there another way to be more clever, without that manual tuple unpacking?

Comment: Isn't this just a specialization of the `StateT` constructor?

Comment: @bisserlis ahah, I think you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well. Thanks @bisserlis.

```
stateIO = StateT
```

(perhaps applied to avoid monomorphism restriction).